# C assembly pushl not working for WriteFile function

Tags: winapi, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

i used C-assembly to call the (_GetStdHandle@4) function to get (output) handle then used (_WriteFile@20) function to write my string on console using handle that i got from (_GetStdHandle@4).
i used (pushl) in my source code for each function to pass the parameters but something's is wrong because (WriteFile)) function return error (6) which is invalid handle but the handle is valid ... so something's wrong with passing argument ... yes ... my problem is passing argument to (_WriteFile) function using (pushl) ... in this code, i used (g) for each argument because there is no reason to move the parameters to register then push the registers ... so i didn't used (r) but if i use (r), the program work without any problem (which mov the parameters to registers first then push the registers (which i want to push the parameters without moving them into the registers)
this code is show nothing and the problem is from (WriteFile) function and if i use (r) for (WriteFile) parameters, the print will be done but why i can't use "g" to not mov the parameters to registers ?

```
    typedef void * HANDLE;

#define GetStdHandle(result, handle)                                    \
    __asm (                                                             \
        "pushl  %1\n\t"                                                 \
        "call   _GetStdHandle@4"                                        \
            : "=a" (result)                                             \
            : "g" (handle))

#define WriteFile(result, handle, buf, buf_size, written_bytes)         \
    __asm (                                                             \
        "pushl  $0\n\t"                                                 \
        "pushl  %1\n\t"                                                 \
        "pushl  %2\n\t"                                                 \
        "pushl  %3\n\t"                                                 \
        "pushl  %4\n\t"                                                 \
        "call   _WriteFile@20"                                          \
            : "=a" (result)                                             \
            : "g" (written_bytes), "g" (buf_size), "g" (buf), "g" (handle))

int main()
{
    HANDLE handle;
    int write_result;
    unsigned long written_bytes;

    GetStdHandle(handle, -11);
    if(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        WriteFile(write_result, handle, "Hello", 5, & written_bytes);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the Assembly code for this program is :

```
.file   "main.c"
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section .rdata,"dr"
LC0:
    .ascii "Hello\0"
    .text
    .globl  _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
LFB25:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    call    ___main
/APP
    pushl  $-11
    call   _GetStdHandle@4
 # 0 "" 2
/NO_APP
    movl    %eax, 12(%esp)
    cmpl    $-1, 12(%esp)
    je  L2
    leal    4(%esp), %eax
/APP
    pushl  $0
    pushl  %eax
    pushl  $5
    pushl  $LC0
    pushl  12(%esp)
    call   _WriteFile@20
 # 0 "" 2
/NO_APP
    movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
L2:
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE25:
    .ident  "GCC: (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0"
```

what is the problem ?

Comment: Please try to format your question nicely. Right now it's just a wall of text. Use paragraphs and other spacing. See [this editing and formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Hello ... it's clear ... (why this code is not working !)

Comment: I also recommend that you first of all learn about the ABI and calling conventions of your target platform. Possibly use the function *without* inline assembly, and then check the generated code, to see what the compiler is doing. Then you can easily copy that code if you insist on using inline assembly (why?).

Comment: You should not change the stack pointer before you consumed all the arguments if there is a chance that one of them may be on the stack, as the compiler may generate address relative to the stack pointer. As you can see that's exactly what is happening with `pushl  12(%esp)`. Since you changed `esp` this no longer refers to the correct location, hence invalid handle.

Comment: nice .. i know that is the problem ... can you give me a solution ?

Comment: It's unclear why you are doing it this way. If you want assembly, use a separate assembly module where you have full control so you can access arguments as appropriate. If you insist on inline asm, do not allow memory operands (but you already know that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would question the need for calling the WINAPI through wrappers like this rather than calling them directly.  You can declare prototypes for the stdcall calling convention with
`__attribute__((stdcall))`

If you don't need to use inline assembly you shouldn't. GCC's inline assembly is hard to get right. Getting it wrong can make the code appear to work until one day it doesn't, especially if optimizations are enabled. David Wohlferd has a good article on why you [shouldn't use inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm) if you don't need to.

---

The primary problem can be seen in this section of generated code:

```
pushl  $0
pushl  %eax
pushl  $5
pushl  $LC0
pushl  12(%esp)
call   _WriteFile@20
```

GCC has computed the memory operand (handle) for the first parameter as `12(%esp)` . The problem is that you have altered *ESP* with the previous pushes and now offset `12(%esp)` is no longer where `handle` is.

To get around this problem you can pass memory addresses through registers or as immediates (if possible). Rather than use `g` constraint which includes `m` (memory constraints), simply use `ri` for registers and immediates. This prevents memory operands from being generated. If you pass pointers through registers you will also need to add the `"memory"` clobber.

The [STDCALL(WINAPI) calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall) allows a function to destroy *EAX*, *ECX*, and *EDX* (AKA the *volatile registers*). It is possible that `GetStdHandle` and `WriteFile` will clobber *ECX* and *EDX* as well as return a value in *EAX*. You need to ensure that *ECX* and *EDX* are listed as clobbers as well (or have a constraint that marks it as output), otherwise the compiler may assume the values in those registers are the same before and after the inline assembly blocks are completed. If they are different it could cause subtle bugs.

With these changes your code could look something like:

```
#define INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE (void *)-1    
typedef void *HANDLE;

#define GetStdHandle(result, handle)                                    \
    __asm (                                                             \
        "pushl  %1\n\t"                                                 \
        "call   _GetStdHandle@4"                                        \
            : "=a" (result)                                             \
            : "g" (handle)                                              \
            : "ecx", "edx")

#define WriteFile(result, handle, buf, buf_size, written_bytes)         \
    __asm __volatile (                                                  \
        "pushl  $0\n\t"                                                 \
        "pushl  %1\n\t"                                                 \
        "pushl  %2\n\t"                                                 \
        "pushl  %3\n\t"                                                 \
        "pushl  %4\n\t"                                                 \
        "call   _WriteFile@20"                                          \
            : "=a" (result)                                             \
            : "ri" (written_bytes), "ri" (buf_size), "ri" (buf), "ri" (handle) \
            : "memory", "ecx", "edx")

int main()
{
    HANDLE handle;
    int write_result;
    unsigned long written_bytes;

    GetStdHandle(handle, -11);
    if(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        WriteFile(write_result, handle, "Hello", 5, &written_bytes);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Notes**:

- I marked the `WriteFile` inline assembly as `__volatile` so that the optimizer can't remove the entire inline assembly if it thinks `result` isn't being used. The compiler doesn't know that a side effect of the function is that the display is updated. Mark the function volatile to prevent the inline assembly from being removed entirely.
- `GetStdHandle` doesn't have a problem with potential memory operands because there are no further uses of constraints after the initial `push %1`. The problem you are encountering is only an issue when *ESP* has been modified (via a PUSH/POP or change to *ESP* directly) and there is a possible use of a memory constraint in that inline assembly afterwards.

Comment: There were some updates from the original as I had a couple of variants and posted the wrong one originally (that had a bug).

Comment: hey ... thank you for your answer ... the (HANDLE) type is using (void *) in windows.h

Comment: @Jason : has been a while, I forgot how it was defined in Windows.h

Comment: is it better to use (r) instead of (g) in GetStdHandle too ?

Comment: PS: I amended the answer to use `void *` and removed the commentary about HANDLE that I had originally.

Comment: Why don't you just declare these functions with  `__attribute__((stdcall))` and call them normally?

Comment: @fuz: because in his comment he has said **i just want to understand what happen on WINAPI functions while we call them** I have asked him that question, and he gave a response. For some reason he wishes to know how it works under the hood. I would have personally done that by writing it in assembly outside of GCC, but the OP was intent on using inline assembly for this. I'm not sure if your comment is directed at me for providing a solution or to Jason (You didn't tag him). My preamble already suggested I questioned the motivations of using inline assembly.

Comment: Is `__volatile` guaranteed to be defined as `__volatile__` or something?  It seems to work on Godbolt, but https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Alternate-Keywords.html only documents adding `__` to both the start *and* end.

Comment: @PeterCordes In the Windows GCC compilers it is defined. I only used that convention. I would normally use __ on beginning and end __. I had considered modifying that so it was the same convention. Since someone (you) was willing to bring it up it is a very simple mod. I have a feeling the underscores at the beginning only for Windows are because of the way MS defines `__asm` for their inline assembly. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/asm?view=vs-2019  . It is the only reason I believe they appear in Windows GCC

Comment: @PeterCordes : What I can confirm is that GCC for native Windows targets accepts `__asm` and `__volatile` as well as `__asm__` and `__volatile__`. Don't know if that is documented anywhere by GCC, but it is a reality.

Comment: @PeterCordes : [Intel C (ICC)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-inline-assembly) has this to say for **Microsoft Compatibility** : "If the optional keyword `volatile` is given, the asm is volatile. Two volatile asm statements are never moved past each other, and a reference to a volatile variable is not moved relative to a volatile asm. Alternate keywords `__volatile__` and `__volatile` may be used for compatibility." . Would appear GCC for Windows targets has adopted the same strategy.

Comment: Linux gcc / clang / ICC on Godbolt accept it, too (https://godbolt.org/z/FfLx9O ; clang chokes on the `@4` inside the asm with its built-in assembler, not the `__asm`).  I just found it odd to see this unusual usage.  If that's what you're used to typing, then I guess it's fine in practice and unlikely to ever be dropped or class with a CPP macro.

Comment: @PeterCordes : I should point out when I said _I only used that convention_ - I meant to say _I only used that convention because the OP did_

Comment: @PeterCordes : Regarding your edit, I should point out that on GCC for WIndows (not referring to other platforms) also supports `__stdcall`, you don't actually need `__attribute__((stdcall))`. You don't even need to include a header, it is seen as a keyword. Again that probably has to do with MS compatibility: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=vs-2019